# Change the Chrome default font

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, fonts

I installed a new font on my Windows 10 machine, and it seems to have become the default font in Google Chrome. How can I restore Chrome's default font?

Answer (score 1):

Click the hamburger icon in the upper-right of Chrome, and click Settings.

[image: Hamburger Icon]

At the bottom of this page, press "Show advanced settings..."
Find the "Web Content" section and press "Customize Fonts".

[image: Web Content]

Change the different fonts in here. Keep in mind that a serif font has little tails and lines on various characters, while a sans-serif font does not.

[image]

For future reference, please specify more details about your problem in the question's title. A better example would be "Installed new font on Windows 10, how do I make Google Chrome stop using it as default?"